# Linq to SQL adding a record to a table that has foreign keys

Tags: linq-to-sql

My goal is to add a record to a table which also has couple of foreign key columns.

For example let's say I have a Company table which has Country ID that references the Country table. When I use linq to sql, I create a new Company object and start filling its properties with data.

Then I say

```
 context.ParentCompanies.InsertOnSubmit(pc);
```

But it gives me Null reference exception. For the Country the Company object has two properties. One is CountryID and the other is Country object. I set the CountryID but I leave Country object as NULL. What should I do to inert my new record?

Comment: Basically you can either assign the Country entity to the company or provide the ID like you do. The error must be caused by something else. Can you post some more code and more details about the error

Comment: If you attempt to insert a record without a required column set, you get a SqlException rather than a null reference exception. You could get a null reference exception if context was null.